# Tool for collecting, annotating, and analyzing social media-/text-data

Tags: database, data-analysis, data, social-networks

I am looking for a tool that allows me to **collect**, **annotate**, and **analyze social media data**. I am interested in collecting data from a variety of sources, including Facebook, Twitter, and Reddit. I would like to be able to annotate the data with metadata, such as the date, time, author, and topic. I would also like to be able to analyze the data to identify trends and patterns.

I have been searching for a tool that meets my needs, but I have not been able to find one that is a good fit. I would appreciate it if you could let me know if you are aware of any tools that meet my needs.

#### Here are some additional details about my use case and the desired features of the tool:

I would like to collect data from a variety of social media platforms, including Facebook, Twitter, and Reddit.
I would like to be able to annotate the data with metadata, such as the date, time, author, and topic.
I would like to be able to analyze the data to identify trends and patterns.
I would like the tool to be easy to use and to have a user-friendly interface.

#### Here is the workflow that I would like to use with the tool:

Collect data from a variety of social media platforms.
Annotate the data with metadata, such as the date, time, author, and topic. The metadata can be predefined or added spontaneously.
Analyze the data to identify trends and patterns.
Share the findings with others.

I would like the tool to be easy to use and to have a user-friendly interface. I am not a programmer and I do not have any experience with SQL, Python, or other programming languages. I would appreciate any feedback or suggestions that you may have.

Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Do you want to analyze the data as quickly as possible (then this dataset will have 0 or very few interactions e.g. retweets), or do you want to analyze more mature data that has seen a lot of interactions?
In any case, as a nonprogrammer, you could contact the platforms themselves and ask if they have apps, service offerings or daughter firms that do provide value-added services and datasets.

Comment: The entire data collection process should consist of a manual part and an automated part. The manual part would be to find the posts, enter the different posts into the tool (i.e. text, interactions, medium, topic, sentiment, etc.). This work would not be spared and that would be perfectly okay.

Comment: The automated part of the job would be to first provide an overview of the metadata, which can be selected for a post by clicking on it. Secondly, the data analysis at the end, so that you can easily determine when, where, how much and what was talked about in a certain period of time. Since contributions from a variety of platforms are collected for this process, many of which do not offer API integration, contacting the providers of these platforms is not really an option. I was thinking of a content management program or something like that, is there such a thing?

Comment: Try chatGPT-4 and the new code interpreter. Upload the dataset and ask it in natural language do do some analyses. Access to this feature will cost 20$/month.

Comment: The main use case would be the storage and categorization of data. I would be looking for such a program.